# Different output when a tcl script is launched via tclsh and wish interpreters

Tags: tcl

I wrote a Tcl script to telnet a Linux server and perform some operations in it.

I send some command and `expect *` (expected everything to be captured in buffer).

Now I print the `$expect_out(buffer)` in a file.

Note: the command I send to the linux server invokes some sort of application in Linux (like a `top` command), but the output of that command is always the same if executed any number of times.

1. Double clicking the script file or `wish script.tcl` (using wish interpreter)

   After completing the execution, I open the file and check for its contents. It has the contents of previous expect, i.e., a previous expect before `expect *` in the script, and some part of this expect (`expect *`). So the file content misses some text at the end.
2. Running the script from command prompt (using tclsh interpreter)

   ```
   #> tclsh script.tcl
   ```

   After completing the execution, I open the file and check for its contents. It has the contents of previous expect, i.e., a previous expect before `expect *` in script, and a all part of this expect (`expect *`).

In the above cases, if `expect *` is replaced with some text like -> `expect "hello"`, then the script fails in wish interpreter and suceeds in tclsh interpreter.

Why is that? How can I fix it?

The script is as below

```
package require Expect  
set DOWN2 \033OB  
spawn telnet 172.19.10.10  
after 30000  
expect "login:"  
send "admin\r"  
expect "Password:"  
after 1000  
send "welcome123\r"  
after 2000  
expect {  
    timeout { exit 1 }  
    "MAIN"  
    }  
expect ">"   
after 3000  
send "mgmt\r"  
expect {  
    timeout { send_user "timed out, Bye "; exit 1 }  
    "Protocol"  
    }  
#set fp [open textdoc.txt a+]  
send "translation\r"  
expect "prefix" 
send "\r\r"  
send "$DOWN2"  
send "$DOWN2"  
send "$DOWN2"  
send "$DOWN2"   
send "326"  
send "\x16"  
expect -re {limit No. : (\d+)}  
set lim_val $expect_out(1,string)  
set exp_out $expect_out(buffer)  
set fp [open textdoc.txt a+]  
puts $fp "total buffer is $exp_out"  
close $fp  
after 2000  
exit
```

This code is successful with tclsh and fails for wish interpreter
fails at line >> `set lim_val $expect_out(1,string)`
But from the wireshark capture, I have found out that the text "limit No. : 2" is received even if run from wish.

If I try to print `$expect_out(buffer)` in file,
In tclsh, the contents stored in buffer is till the  "limit No. : 2" is occurred
In wish, the contents stored in buffer ends even before the text "limit No. : 2" is occurred.

Comment: Can you include some minimal code that actually exhibits the problem? What are you `spawn`ing? (If you can see it with something small and commonly available, so much the better.)

Comment: Added the script file. Also please tell me that, can a tclsh script be invoked (run) from a wish script ?